# How to compare value of column to all rows of a column on a seperate dataFrame on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, text-processing

I have those two dataframes .

[image]
[image]

My goal is to compare each value of Column "FilteredDescription" on the first dataframe to all values of the Column "Name" on the second dataframe.

Comment: compare & after that what you have to do ? what you have to do if matches & not matches values ??

Comment: Exactly i want to get the maximum similarity value between each "FiltredDescription" and all "Names" (i am using jaro winkler)

Comment: can you give me one example .. take one value from two dfs ?? if possible

Comment: This is the function that i wrote , of course it is a bad logic , but i think this can help you to understand the situation
'''
var distance = Udf((string column, IEnumerable<string> allValues) =>
                allValues.Max(x => Jw.Distance(x, column))); '''

Comment: which language are you using ??

Comment: I am using C#, i tried even with java and i am facing the same problem .

Comment: I am just added below answer, please check & let me know if its not helping or correct me if understood your requirement wrong.. :)

Comment: Thank you i appreciate that , I will try , i am not experienced in scala but i will try to do the same with c# or java .

Comment: I have used ```crossJoin``` function .. to compare column from both ```dataframe``` .. let me know if its not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not mentioned complete flow of your logic, I am just adding below logic to match one column from both tables.

```
//load data for first dataframe.
val dfa = dfaData.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id).withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"id".asc)))
//load data for second dataframe.
val dfb = dfbData.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id).withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"id".asc)))

//Used cross join to match dfa columns to dfb columns.
dfa.crossJoin(dfb).withColumn("matched",when($"filtereddescription" === $"name", lit("matched")).otherwise("not matched")).show(false)
```